# Not running with replSet option MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a small replica set on my computer in Windows.

Here is what I have done so far:

I have made three directories in data by

`mkdir \data\rs1 \data\rs2 \data\rs3`

Now, I am starting three mongo instances:

```
start mongod --replSet m101 --logpath 1.log --dbpath \data\rs1 --port 27017 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64

start mongod --replSet m101 --logpath 2.log --dbpath \data\rs2 --port 27018 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64

start mongod --replSet m101 --logpath 3.log --dbpath \data\rs3 --port 27019 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64
```

Now I am starting mongod.exe by command line and connect to a mongo shell by typing

`mongo --port 27017`

Here is my replica set:

```
config = { _id: "m101", members:[
          { _id : 0, host : "localhost:27017"},
          { _id : 1, host : "localhost:27018"},
          { _id : 2, host : "localhost:27019"} ]
};
```

Now when I type `rs.initiate(config);` , It shows this node was not started with replSet option.

I also tried to run command line options on admin

```
use admin
db.runCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
```

and I don't see any --replSet options in there.

I get

```
{
      "argv" : [ "mongod" ],
      "parsed" : {},
      "ok" : 1
}
```

I know many questions related to this problem are available and I tried many of them but none of them worked. I am new to this and learning this from one of the courses of MongoDB University. Please can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's better to post your question on your course discussion forum rather than SO.

Comment: Given your output from `getCmdLineOpts` doesn't include any other options I suspect you are connecting to a running standalone instance of `mongod` (perhaps started before your replica set). I would make sure you have stopped any other running instances before standing up your replica set.